# passing "this" to a thread c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, inheritance, this

What is the best way of performing the following in C++. Whilst my current method works I'm not sure it's the best way to go:

1) I have a master class that has some function in it

2) I have a thread that takes some instructions on a socket and then runs one of the functions in the master class

3) There are a number of threads that access various functions in the master class

I create the master class and then create instances of the thread classes from the master.  The constructor for the thread class gets passed the "this" pointer for the master.  I can then run functions from the master class inside the threads - i.e. I get a command to do something which runs a function in the master class from the thread.  I have mutex's etc to prevent race problems.

Am I going about this the wrong way - It kinda seems like the thread classes should inherit the master class or another approach would be to not have separate thread classes but just have them as functions of the master class but that gets ugly.

Comment: Could you post some code? Are you aware of the distinction between classes and instances? Is there one master class instance for each thread?

Comment: No there is a single master class from which the threads get spawned.  The threads just need to access the masters member functions and some variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds good to me.  In my servers, it is called 'SCB' - ServerControlBlock - and provides access to services like the IOCPbuffer/socket pools, logger, UI access for status/error messages and anything else that needs to be common to all the handler threads.  Works fine and I don't see it as a hack.

I create the SCB, (and ensure in the ctor that all services accessed through it are started and ready for use), before creating the thread pool that uses the SCB - no nasty singletonny stuff.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: Ok sounds good - I'll continue using "this" in my thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

Separate thread classes is pretty normal, especially if they have specific functionality.  I wouldn't inherit from the main thread.

Comment: Yep I guess the main question I have is passing the "this" pointer to the thread classes bad coding or is it fairly standard.  It feels like a bit of a hack

Comment: It is not a hack if you treat the master class as a singleton etc.

Comment: Passing the "this" pointer is normal, it's a common thing to do.  As Aditya said, you could also make your main class a singleton so that you wouldn't pass any pointer at all, you would just call MainClass::getInst()-> whenver you wanted access methods on it.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the `this` pointer to threads is not, in itself, bad.  What you do with it can be.

The `this` pointer is just like any other POD-ish data type.  It's just a chunk of bits.  The stuff that is in `this` might be more than PODs however, and passing what is in effect a pointer to it's members can be dangerous for all the usual reasons.  Any time you share anything across threads, it introduces potential race conditions and deadlocks.  The elementary means to resolve those conflicts is, of course, to introduce synchronization in the form of mutexes, semaphores, etc, but this can have the suprising effect of serializing your application.

Say you have one thread reading data from a socket and storing it to a synchronized command buffer, and another thread which reads from that command buffer.  Both threads use the same mutex, which protects the buffer.  All is well, right?

Well, maybe not.  Your threads could become serialized if you're not very careful with how you lock the buffer.  Presumably you created separate threads for the buffer-insert and buffer-remove codes so that they could run in parallel.  But if you lock the buffer with each insert & each remove, then only one of those operations can be executing at a time.  As long as your writing to the buffer, you can't read from it and vice versa.

You can try to fine-tune the locks so that they are as brief as possible, but so long as you have shared, synchronized data, you will have some degree of serialization.

Another approach is to hand data off to another thread explicitly, and remove as much data sharing as possible.  Instead of writing to and reading from a buffer as in the above, for example, your socket code might create some kind of `Command` object on the heap (eg `Command* cmd = new Command(...);`) and pass that off to the other thread.  (One way to do this in Windows is via the [QueueUserAPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684954%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mechanism).

There are pros & cons to both approaches.  The synchronization method has the benefit of being somewhat simpler to understand and implement at the surface, but the potential drawback of being much more difficult to debug if you mess something up.  The hand-off method can make many of the problems inherent with synchronization impossible (thereby actually making it *simpler*), but it takes time to allocate memory on the heap.